# Writing HTTP POST content to could storage?

Tags: http-post, google-drive-api, dropbox, http-get, http-request

is it possible to create a file in my Dropbox/Google drive (or any could service) via HTTP POST and GET only ?

I want to send a HTTP POST with text content in it and whatever the content is it will be written to a file in my storage.

i was able to do this on a free web hosting using PHP but it is possible to be done on could or maybe is it possible to host PHP on cloud so i can use the same PHP code the i used on the site ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. For Dropbox, see https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put.

Answer (score 0):

For Drive, see [Uploading files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads).  It talks through the steps for uploading file content over http.